# What's the difference between kill and taskkill?

Tags: process, kill, kill-process, taskkill

I'm on a Windows 7 machine using Cygwin.

There is a process listening on port 9090 that I wanted to kill.

First, I ran `netstat -ao | grep 9090` to find out its PID `19892`. Then I want to kill it.

```
$ netstat -ao | grep 9090
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State        PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9090           yyyyyyyyyy:0        LISTENING       19892
  TCP    xx.xx.xx.xxx:58278     yyyyyyyyyy:9090     TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    xx.xx.xx.xxx:58280     yyyyyyyyyy:9090     TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    [::]:9090              yyyyyyyyyy:0        LISTENING       19892
```

**Attempt 1** `kill -9 19892` fails to kill the process, giving error

```
-sh: kill: (19892) - No such process
```

**Attempt 2** `taskkill /PID 19892` fails to kill the process, giving error

```
ERROR: The process with PID 19892 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
```

**Attempt 3** `taskkill /F /PID 19892` works

```
SUCCESS: The process with PID 19892 has been terminated.
```

---

**Question:**

How are `kill` and `taskkill` different?

Why do I need the `/F` option here?

What does the `/F` option do exactly? (apparently it's something more than sending SIGKILL)

> /f   : Specifies that process(es) be forcefully terminated. This parameter is ignored for remote processes; all remote processes are forcefully terminated [(source)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx)

Comment: Well, `taskkill(.exe)` is a windows tool, and `kill` is from cygwin. That may have something to do with it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yeah - Correct me if I'm mistaken, but I thought `kill -9` is the "strongest" kill one can do on Unix systems (and assumed the equivalent on Windows). On Windows it seems `taskkill /F` is even stronger.